# Why won't mapbox map load into DIV container?

Tags: mapbox

I cannot figure out why I cannot load a map into a CSS template that I am trying to customize.

I have placed a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mapbaker/Du7zq/10/

Basically I'm trying to get a map to load into the red DIV Container (called mapBox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
var map = mapbox.map('map');
```

to

```
var map = mapbox.map('mapBox');
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32573174/13221322) to [positioning a mapbox/leaflet map inside a container div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571611) at Stack Overflow, and is reproduced below the line:

What you forgot to do here was define an absolute height for the map.

---

The only css rule that ***must*** be set for Leaflet's (Mapbox is an extended version of [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com)) element when positioned static/relative is an absolute height:

```
#map {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/vdeyLv?p=preview

That will work always, doesn't matter how deep the element is nested. When width  is not set it will use all the width available. When you want to switch to setting height in percentages, you'll need to make sure that all the anchestor elements of the map element have a height set also:

```
#html, #body, #map-container {
    height: 100%;
}

#map {
    height: 40%;
}
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/rAuNC0?p=preview

I guess the reasoning behind using absolute positioning in the Mapbox examples is that one does not have to explain the above because no matter how deep you nest the map's element, it just works.